# react-native run-android in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to React Native language, and I'm having difficulty in running the app in Android.

The eror is :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.> 
 java.io.IOException: Could not delete path'C:\Users\Documents\projectFolder\android\app\build\generated\source\r\debug\android\support\graphics\drawable'.
```

and in my package.json

```
    "name": "sampleProject",
    "version": "0.1.6",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
    "start": "rm -rf __globals__ && cp -fR ../../globals __globals__ && npm run lint && node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "ios": "rm -rf __globals__ && cp -fR ../../globals __globals__ && npm run lint && react-native run-ios",
    "android": "rm -rf __globals__ && cp -fR ../../globals __globals__ && npm run lint && react-native run-android",
    "log-ios": "react-native log-ios",
    "log-android": "react-native log-android",
    "test": "jest",
    "reset": "rm -rf __globals__ && cp -fR ../../globals __globals__ && npm run 
    lint && node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start --reset-
    cache",
    "lint": "eslint --fix --max-warnings 1 .",
    "precommit": "npm run lint"
    },
   "dependencies": {
    "async": "~2.4.1",
    "bluebird": "~3.5.0",
    "color-term-console": "~1.0.4",
    "crypto-js": "~3.1.9-1",
    "file-extension": "~3.1.2",
    etc ...
```

what should I do guys ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

goto android folder by using command `cd android` then run `./gradlew clean`

Now go back to your project folder by `cd ..`

Then `react-native run-android`

Comment: I try running the "cd android && ./gradlew clean" but its error. it says. '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: try using one by one i.e. dont use `&&` .try doing stepwise

Answer (score 0):

**Automatic Method**

`./android/gradlew clean` (Remove ./ in win cmd)

**Manual Method**

Remove build files from `android/build` and `android/app/build`